# distributed software development methodologies

Tags: distributed

is there any methodology about distributed software development that really works? by distributed i mean long distance, developers stay in different cities or countries.

Comment: That's how lots of open source software is written.  Some people never sit face to face across from co-developers.

Comment: @vincent : yes , thnx :D

Comment: @duffymo : yes i know that! so there should be some standard method or something

Comment: i just want to know your experiences with these stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end it depends on the rules defined by the team.

you will use distributed version control like

- git
- mercurial
- bazaar
- etc.

where you will develop, test and deploy your different branches in dedicated environment like

- stable
- staging
- development

basically you will pass an issue/feature from development to stable via a distributed team of developers.

coordinating this and having a common understanding of the process is the challenge and not that easy to achieve.

hope this gives you an overview.